# VK-bot на python: Ошибка vk_api.exceptions.ApiError - что его не устраивает в моих values?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

> ```
> vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was
>   missing or invalid: all values except 8 are deprecated for 'filter'
>   parameter
> ```

Вот такая-вот ошибка выскакивает при данном коде:

```
import vk_api, time

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='token')
# vk.auth()

values = {'out': 0, 'count': 100, 'time_offset': 60}  # Похоже, что именно здесь и возникает ошибка.

def write_msg(user_id, s):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id':user_id,'message':s})

while True:
    response = vk.method('messages.get', values)
    if response['items']:
        values['last_message_id'] = response['items'][0]['id']
    for item in response['items']:
        write_msg(item[u'user_id'],u'Привет, Хабр!')
time.sleep(1)
```

Вот, сопсна, стараюсь понять, из-за чего. А так это все то же самое, что и здесь: https://habr.com/post/326312/

Буду крайне благодарен, если кто-нибудь сможет помочь.

Comment: Не стесняйтесь читать документацию: [Данный метод устарел и может быть отключён через некоторое время, пожалуйста, избегайте его использования.](https://vk.com/dev/messages.get)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. Что-то как-то я совсем упустил этот комментарий. Полагаю, что вместо этого придется использовать какой-то другой.

Comment: Впрочем, и про filters там тоже упомянуто: у вас оно не указано и по умолчанию 0, а должно быть указано 8 (почему, не знаю, с messages.get никогда не работал)

Comment: да, я изначально указал 'filter', но там же вроде значение должно быть какое-нибудь типа "unread", разве нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот метод устарел. Используйте метод `messages.getConversations`.

В дополнение, filter должен иметь параметр "important", "unread" и др., смотреть здесь: https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversations